# Select ID by two different conditions on two column on a table

Tags: sql, conditional-statements

I have a table that looks like this:

| user_id | method | car_brand |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | car | honda |
| 345678 | walk |  |
| 567890 | walk |  |
| 567890 | car | toyota |

I want to get the `user_id`, where the method is walk and the car_brand is not toyota.

The expected output is:

| user_id | method | car_brand |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 345678 | walk |  |

Since the user 567890 has toyota in the `car_brand`.

What query do I know to get this result?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do the "walk" records have no car brand?  This looks like a questionable table design to me.

Comment: From my perspective, ... any records with `method` is `walk` should not have any value for `car_brand` right?

Answer (score 3):

you could use a query like below

```
select t1.* 
from yourtable t1 where
method='walk'
and not exists 
(
select 1 from yourtable t2
where t2.user_id=t1.user_id and t2.car_brand ='toyota')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly not the most efficient method, but it shows how you may 'pivot' the table to be in a form that's easier to query for the type of question you're asking:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  `user_id` INTEGER,
  `method` VARCHAR(4),
  `car_brand` VARCHAR(6)
);

INSERT INTO t
  (`user_id`, `method`, `car_brand`)
VALUES
  ('123456', 'car', 'honda'),
  ('345678', 'walk', NULL),
  ('567890', 'walk', NULL),
  ('567890', 'car', 'toyota');
```

---

**Pivot Query**

```
SELECT user_id
     , MAX(CASE WHEN method = 'car' THEN 'car' END) car
     , MAX(CASE WHEN method = 'walk' THEN 'walk' END) walk
     , MAX(car_brand) car_brand
FROM t
GROUP BY user_id;
```

| user_id | car | walk | car_brand |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | car |  | honda |
| 345678 |  | walk |  |
| 567890 | car | walk | toyota |

---

**Desired Output**

```
SELECT user_id
     , walk method
     , car_brand
FROM (
  SELECT user_id
       , MAX(CASE WHEN method = 'car' THEN 'car' END) car
       , MAX(CASE WHEN method = 'walk' THEN 'walk' END) walk
       , MAX(car_brand) car_brand
  FROM t
  GROUP BY user_id
) t2
WHERE COALESCE(car_brand, '') <> 'toyota'
  AND walk IS NOT NULL;
```

| user_id | method | car_brand |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 345678 | walk |  |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aZaNHUktQfDPHWzw6jvbf3/3)